# Is a const array automatically loaded to flash?

Tags: memory, constants, iar

I am using an IAR IDE with a Cortex M4 based MCU. When I declare an array to be const does it automatically assign it to flash memory rather than RAM?

Answer (score 0):

By experiment, using a global array marked as const, it get loaded to flash. If const is omitted it gets mapped into RAM

Answer (score 0):

This is determined by your linker configuration. You can configure your linker to not touch flash at all, but it won't be very useful, since at power-on, your processor won't contain the code or initialization data to initialize memory. Typically, code (not defined as ramfunc), read only data, and initialization values for read/write data will end up in flash, and I believe IAR's linker scripts are setup to map this way by default.

In your experiment, using const puts the variable directly into flash. If you had an initialized value (presumably you did, since it was const), then removing const means it will be placed in read/write data section, but there will be a copy in flash (if using the default script) to initialize the RAM copy from.